# google api using phonegap not showing map and latitude and longitude

Tags: android, cordova

I am using Google Maps using Phone Gap. It's working on a mobile website that I have created using jquerymobile framework, but when I copy the project in Eclipse using phonegap to test it on the emulator it does not work.its working on actual device but not working on emulator.

Code files:

config.xml

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
 <access origin="google.com"; /> 
<access origin="maps.google.com"/>
 <access origin="google.com"; />
 <access origin="maps.google.com*"/>
```

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
     <html>
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>

   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>

<!-- CSS Style Sheetes -->

    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
     <link rel="icon" href="images/IconTaxi.png" type="image/x-icon">

<!--  JavaScript -->

     <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">     </script>
      <script src="js/cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div class="headerStyle">
        <h2 class="headingHeader"><img class="headerImage" src="images/flag.png" alt"United Arab Emirates" / ></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <h1 class="headingImage">Welcome </h1>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview" class="mainmenu">
            <li><a href="companyList.html">Get Companies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#AboutUs">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

On this page I am showing  map when user switch on userRequest.html:

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
               <html>
                <head>
                </head>

               <body>

               <div id="userRequest" data-role="page" >

            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <a href="companyList.html" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-left" data-icon="back" data-inline="true" data-transition="slide" data-theme="e">Back</a>
            <h1 id="getComapnyHeader"></h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" id="requestForm" style="background:none">           
               <div class="content-primary">
                   <form id="userOrder">
                        <div style="padding:10px 0px;">
                          <label for="userName" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
                          <input type="text" name="userName" required ="required" id="userName" value="" placeholder="Your Name" required data-theme="e" />

                          <label for="userPhone" class="ui-hidden-accessible">PhoneNumber:</label>
                          <input type="tel" name="userPhone" required ="required" id="userPhone" value="" placeholder="PhoneNumber" required data-theme="e" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="map"></div>
                    </form>


        </div>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // setup global error handler
    window.onerror = function (message, url, lineNumber) {
        console.log([lineNumber, url, message].join(" "));
        return false;
    };

    console.log("document.ready");
    console.log(window.location.hash);

    // start the app
    app.init();
});

var app = app || { _timeStart: null };

app.init = function () {

    app.Lati = 0;
    app.longi = 0;
    $('#userRequest').live('pageshow', function(e) { app.getGeoLocation(e); });
 });

};

app.getGeoLocation = function(e) {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(app.onGeoSuccess, app.onGeoError);

}; 

app.onGeoError = function(error) {
    if(error == 1 )
    {
        alert("Turn On Geo Location");
    }
};

app.onGeoSuccess = function(position)
{
     var lat = position.coords.latitude;
     var lon = position.coords.longitude;
     var currentPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

    var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: currentPosition,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: true
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: currentPosition, 
            map: map, 
        });

        app.Lati = lat;
        app.longi = lon;
        console.log(app.Lati);

};
```

Comment: is there any error in logcat?

Comment: no there is no error related. even same code works fine on browser even getting lat and long and showing map but when i am using this code for andorid using phonegap its not working

here in confif.xml file i added

<access origin="" subdomains="true"/> <access origin="google.com"; /> <access origin="maps.google.com"/> <access origin="google.com"; /> <access origin="maps.google.com*"/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odds are you're probably not whitelisting correctly.

From a quick glance it looks like you need to be whitelisting:

- code.jquery.com
- Items related to google maps.

Honestly you should really download the jQuery and have it locally rather than trying to retrieve it from the CDN.

The google maps items can be a little tricky since it has a lot of dependencies. A list that might work is:

- *.google.com
- *.googleapis.com
- *.gstatic.com

Comment: Can you please specify that where my code need the changes related to Google Maps? As you mention the links *.google.com etc ?

Comment: You put the code in config.xml.  Go to the PhoneGap Documentation and look at Domain Whitelisting

Comment: <access origin="*" /> 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html in this phonegap documentation mention * allaow for all domains 

i have done this in my config.xml but still nothing happen

Comment: <access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
 <access origin="http://google.com" />
    <access origin="http://maps.google.com*"/>
    <access origin="https://google.com" />
    <access origin="https://maps.google.com*"/>
in config.xml i have done there lines but still lat long not getting as well as map not showing