# google map not showing in phonegap app

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, webview

I am trying to show google map in my app using the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <script scr="jquery.js></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    html, body, #map-canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }

</style>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                                      mapOptions);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

It works fine when my MainActivity.java is like

```
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);
    myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

}     }
```

But google map is not shown when I use

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Is their any way to resolve this. thanks in advance.

Comment: do you set access origin * on config.xml

Comment: @AmitPrajapati I tried origin as * but I am getting "cannot call method appendchild of null" error. I also tried "<access origin="*.google.com"/> <access origin="*.googleapis.com"/>" but of no use, no error and map is not show

Comment: add deviceReady() and call google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); on success

Comment: possible duplicate of [google api using phonegap not showing map and latitute and longitute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305397/google-api-using-phonegap-not-showing-map-and-latitute-and-longitute)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change meta

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
          content="default-src *;
               script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
                           127.0.0.1:*
                           http://*.google.com
                           http://*.gstatic.com
                           http://*.googleapis.com
                           http://*.firebaseio.com
                           https://*.google.com
                           https://*.gstatic.com
                           https://*.googleapis.com
                           https://*.firebaseio.com
                           ;
               style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline'
                          127.0.0.1
                           http://*.google.com
                           http://*.gstatic.com
                           http://*.googleapis.com
                           http://*.firebaseio.com
                           https://*.google.com
                           https://*.gstatic.com
                           https://*.googleapis.com
                           https://*.firebaseio.com
">
```

and the google script `<script src="https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>`